# minifying js & css with one min file for each jsp page

Tags: javascript, css, minify

I have around 5 major JSPs in my website. Each jsp includes multiple js and css files. I want to minify both the js and css, with one js&css per JSP.

All the plugins which are available speaks about one js & css for entire website, but I would rather want is to have one js/css per JSP. Otherwise on home page loading itself, it would download the full js/css which I donot want.

Can any one please suggest any solution for the same.

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 1):

If those files are just static, then it's better to just pack them into one CSS and one JS. That way, the next few pages will only load the cached versions. But yes, you can still do packing per JSP for ligher pages especially for mobile.

As for tools, there are a lot. [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) and [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) are usually top picks.